# Automatically generate OTA distribution manifest for XIB-less MonoTouch Enterprise app?

Tags: xamarin.ios, manifest, xib, ota, over-the-air

I have an XIB-less Enterprise MonoTouch iPhone app and I need to distribute it over-the-air using a manifest file. Is there a way to generate the manifest file automatically, or must I construct it by hand?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've just copied an existing manifest and modified it.  As I recall there is not much that has to be modified in the manifest.